# How to surround this text that hasn't any HTML tags around it (with jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<span id="subscription-toggle" class="list:subscription">

&nbsp;|&nbsp; <!-- I want to surround this with a div with a class -->

<span class="" id="subscribe-77" style="">
<a class="dim:subscription-toggle:subscribe-77:is-subscribed" href="http://localhost/taiwantalk2/topic/topic-with-two-tags-topic-with-two-tags-topic-with-two-tags/?action=bbp_subscribe&amp;topic_id=77&amp;_wpnonce=25988e5dac">Subscribe</a>
</span>

</span>
```

So this should be the final result:

```
<span id="subscription-toggle" class="list:subscription">

<div class="hide-this">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</div>

<span class="" id="subscribe-77" style="">
<a class="dim:subscription-toggle:subscribe-77:is-subscribed" href="http://localhost/taiwantalk2/topic/topic-with-two-tags-topic-with-two-tags-topic-with-two-tags/?action=bbp_subscribe&amp;topic_id=77&amp;_wpnonce=25988e5dac">Subscribe</a>
</span>

</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the text node you wish to wrap your `div` around is the only text node (i.e. it's the only text inside `subscription-toggle` that is not inside another element) then you can do this:

```
$("#subscription-toggle").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap("<div class='hide-this'></div>");
```

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/uBJCK/).

Alternatively, if there are multiple text nodes in the `span`, and you only want to wrap `|` characters, replace the body of the `filter` function with this line:

`return $(this).text().indexOf("|") != -1;`

You can see an example of that one working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/uBJCK/1/).

Comment: It matches any text node, but not the particular text node (`&nbsp;|&nbsp;`)

Comment: I know, that's why I said it will work if the text node you want to wrap is the only text node in the element. I have since updated the answer with an alternative method to select only text nodes containing the `|` character.

Comment: @James Allardice Thanks I've been looking for this for years. But in your second example the Subscribe link still there (your first example worked but not the second one).

Comment: @alexchenco - The subscribe link is still there in both examples... you wanted to wrap the `|` character in a `div`, not do anything with the subscribe link.

Comment: @James Allardice yeah I mean in the second example the divs don't get wrapped around the `|`.

Comment: @alexchenco - It looks to me like it does. I've made another fiddle in which the `hide-this` class makes the text red, and the `|` appears red, which means it's inside the `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/uBJCK/2/

Comment: @James Allardice sorry I forgot to place a j before the $ symbol (a no conflict measure for Wordpress). Sorry, thanks a lot!.

Comment: No problem, glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested but it should work:

```
var subsc = $('#subscription-toggle');
subsc.html(subsc.html().replace('/(&nbsp;\|&nbsp;)/g', '<div class="hide-this">$1</div>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the `wrap`-function of jquery: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

So you could search for the `&nbsp;|&nbsp;` with a `:contains`-Selector and than use the `wrap`-function.

Comment: sorry I'm not very familiar with that can you give me an example of the code?

Comment: See the answer of James Allardice

Answer (score 0):

how about:

$("#subscription-toggle").prepend(function(){
    return $("").append(this.childNodes[0]);
});